# reading TCP in java issue

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am reading TCP `packets` that I use to display an image. Each packet is supposed to have a `1025` length. And each time, I get `128` lines, I draw an image.

SO I begin by initializing

```
s = new Socket(ip, port);
stream = s.getInputStream();
byte[] tmpBuffer = new byte[1025];
byte[] finalBuffer = new byte[128 * 1025];
int count_lines =0
```

and then I read stream by stream of length 1025,

```
while((read = stream.read(tmpBuffer, 0, tmpBuffer.length)) != -1){
    System.arraycopy(tmpBuffer, 1, finalBuffer, count_lines * 1025, 1025); 
    count_lines++; 
    if(count_lines == 128) break;
}
```

The problem is when I log the `read` integer, I get a bunch of `1025` but sometimes (apparently randomly) `423` or `602` (noticing that `423+602=1025`)

Am I going wrong with the `TCP` reading or is there a problem on the server side ?

Comment: Yes, you are going wrong. TCP packets are treated as data stream and the separation won't be preserved.

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you, is there a way to get them ?

Comment: If you know you will receive 1025 bytes of data, just read that many bytes.  If `stream.read()` returns less, you have to read again.

Comment: @markspace so you mean `read = stream.read(tmpBuffer)` and if  `read`is not equal to 1025, then I read again ?

Comment: Yup.  Count the total bytes, return it it reaches 1025.

Comment: @markspace thank you so much : now, I get for each line buffers of `1025`. In the TCP` server, data of each line is sent through write(client_sock, data_to_send, strlen(data_to_send));` with the first number being the no of the line (this is critical for the image). but, on the android side, when I get the `data`, I get some `tmpBuffer` byte that have indeed the no. of line as the first entry, but randomly others that have the no of lines at random entry. Do you have an idea ? am I still going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I going wrong with the TCP reading or is there a problem on the server side ?

In TCP you have only a stream of bytes.  You have messages nor control over packets which are typically no more than 1532 bytes long.

You have to have your own protocol to handle sending of messages.

`inputStream.read(buffer)` will read between 1 byte and `buffer.length` and you can't ignore the actual length read as you are doing.

If you want to read into a buffer of a known length, you can use

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] finalBuffer = new byte[128 * 1025];
dis.readFully(finalBuffer);
```

The `readFully` reads as much as it can at a time until the `byte[]` has been fully read.

A more flexible protocol is to send the length first.

```
public static void write(DataOutputStream out, byte[] bytes) {
    out.writeInt(bytes.length());
    out.write(bytes);
}

public static byte[] read(DataInputStream in) {
    int length = in.readInt();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    in.readFully(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

This way, whatever length of data you send, you will recieve in the same manner.

Comment: thank you, @markspace told me that I should put `read = stream.read(tmpBuffer) ` and reading byte if and only if `read` is equal to 1025. Is that still correct ?

Comment: @Newben That is not what he/she said. He said if you read less than 1025, you have to read more.